# A word describing the attempt to prevent one from expressing his or her political or personal beliefs

Tags: verbs, nouns, adverbs

I need a word that appropriately describes the verbal or physical attempt at preventing someone from expressing their views.

Comment: ***Suppression***, ***Censorship***, ***Censures***, and anything a thesaurus suggests.

Comment: I think this is a good question, and personally, I'd like to see idioms that mean a similar thing. "bullied into silence" perhaps?

Comment: **Silencing** a person, **suppressing** their opinions, and **censoring** any publication attempting to spread that opinion all are close. But since you ask about _"the attempt to prevent"_, then **muting** or **stifling** might also be useful options.

Comment: @DarshanBaral  I'd post throttle , or particularly "throttle discussion"  well put in my opinion

Comment: I think a lot of these comments should be answers, given the OP post more information like an example sentence so the answers can be narrowed.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please see the tag wiki for information on how to write strong [single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Questions that show no research effort, nor an example of how the word would be used, are subject to being closed. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] to better familiarize yourself with StackExchange and how it works.

Comment: Did the attempt involve rotten tomatoes? Boiling oil? Public ridicule? Poison? Gee, there are so many choices... Please read what @choster wrote.